# Delete software and could not log to PIXEL anymore

Tags: raspbian, pixel

As there are a lot of software in Raspbian.
I delete the software below:

sudo apt-get purge wolfram-engine

sudo apt-get purge sonic-pi

sudo apt-get purge scratch

sudo apt-get purge python

sudo apt-get purge python3

sudo apt-get purge python-pygame

sudo apt-get purge bluej

sudo apt-get purge scratch

sudo apt-get purge nuscratch

sudo apt-get purge greenfoot

sudo apt-get autoremove

After reboot, I could not log in to PIXEL anymore. I have input the right password, but it does not work.
I do not know why.
What should I do to log in to PIXEL again.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't delete python and python3 on the Raspberry Pi unless you are really sure what you are doing. A lot of components in Raspbian/Noobs etc. are written in the Python language and thus, like the python interpreters dearly.

As you did "autoremove", you deleted all these components, which leaves you with a broken system. I think a complete reinstall should be simpler than trying to fix everything by hand.